# Pandas: create a new column and give each row different values based on the presence of values of a given range over a specific range of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to stackoverflow & also to data analysis with python.
Right now I'm stuck at preliminary phases of df cleaning with pandas library.

I'm working on a df like this

```
  Animal_ID weight  Project   Exp_type   researcher events_d1 events_d2 events_d3 events_d4     
0     a1    50        p1        Acute      alex         0         0         0         4
1     a2    52        p2        chronic    mat          0         1         1         5
2     a3    75        p1        Acute      alex         1                   2
3     a4    53        p2        chronic    mat          0                             0
```

I would like to insert a column named "responder" and populate each row with y/n attribute according to the presence of at least one event (i.e. at least a single value>0) in the range of columns [events_d1..3 but not in events_d4].
To me it is quite important to select as many events_d* columns as needed without listing them all, but selecting them with something similar to df.filter(like='events_d', axis=1) command.
My final goal is that df_output appears something like that:

```
  Animal_ID weight  responder Project   Exp_type   researcher events_d1 events_d2 events_d3 events_d4     
0     a1    50      n          p1        Acute      alex         0         0         0         4
1     a2    52      y          p2        chronic    mat          0         1         1         5
2     a3    75      y          p1        Acute      alex         1                   2
3     a4    53      n          p2        chronic    mat          0                             0
```

I tried to solve the issue using query OR concatenating str.contains([1-9]) and filter but it did not work. I was curious about the approach you would use.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Pietro

Comment: Text is always better than images as it is copyable. Images are highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster, I will avoid images in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter` with regex to exclude `4`

```
m = df.filter(regex="events_d[^4]").any(axis=1)
df['responder'] = np.where(m,'y','n')
df
```

|  | Animal_ID | weight | Project | Exp_type | researcher | events_d1 | events_d2 | events_d3 | events_d4 | responder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a1 | 50 | p1 | Acute | alex | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | n |
| 1 | a2 | 52 | p2 | chronic | mat | 0 | 1 | 1 | 5 | y |
| 2 | a3 | 75 | p1 | Acute | alex | 1 | nan | 2 | nan | y |
| 3 | a4 | 53 | p2 | chronic | mat | 0 | nan | nan | 0 | n |

Answer (score 0):

I defines a custom function check_responder which filters the relevant columns using df.filter(like='events_d', axis=1), and then checks the conditions for the 'responder' column. The apply function is used to apply this function to each row of the dataframe, and the result is stored in the new 'responder' column. event_d4 is excluded

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Animal_ID': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
        'weight': [50, 52, 75, 53],
        'Project': ['p1', 'p2', 'p1', 'p2'],
        'Exp_type': ['Acute', 'chronic', 'Acute', 'chronic'],
        'researcher': ['alex', 'mat', 'alex', 'mat'],
        'events_d1': [0, 0, 1, 0],
        'events_d2': [0, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
        'events_d3': [0, 1, 2, np.nan],
        'events_d4': [4, 5, np.nan, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to check if there is at least one event greater than 0 (excluding events_d4)
def check_responder(row):
    events_columns = df.filter(like='events_d', axis=1).columns[:-1]  # Exclude events_d4
    events_values = row[events_columns]
    return 'y' if any(events_values > 0) else 'n'

# Create the 'responder' column
df['responder'] = df.apply(check_responder, axis=1)

# Replace NaN values with empty string
df = df.fillna('')

print(df)
  Animal_ID  weight Project Exp_type researcher  events_d1 events_d2  \
0        a1      50      p1    Acute       alex          0       0.0   
1        a2      52      p2  chronic        mat          0       1.0   
2        a3      75      p1    Acute       alex          1             
3        a4      53      p2  chronic        mat          0             

  events_d3 events_d4 responder  
0       0.0       4.0         n  
1       1.0       5.0         y  
2       2.0                   y  
3                 0.0         n
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the logic to exclude the column, you can process the output of [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

To exclude a specific name, with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df['responder'] = np.where(df
                           .filter(like='events_')
                           .drop(columns='events_d4',   errors='ignore')
                           .eq(1).any(axis=1),
                           'y', 'n'
                           )
```

To remove the last column with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['responder'] = np.where(df
                          .filter(like='events_')
                          .iloc[:, :-1]
                          .eq(1).any(axis=1),
                          'y', 'n'
                          )
```

Output:

```
  Animal_ID  weight Project Exp_type researcher  events_d1  events_d2  events_d3  events_d4 responder
0        a1      50      p1    Acute       alex          0        0.0        0.0        4.0         n
1        a2      52      p2  chronic        mat          0        1.0        1.0        5.0         y
2        a3      75      p1    Acute       alex          1        NaN        2.0        NaN         y
3        a4      53      p2  chronic        mat          0        NaN        NaN        0.0         n
```